# Passing a complex object to an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have read almost topics here how to pass a complex object to an activity. There are two ways to do:

1) Serializable object

2) Parcelable object

All the examples I saw are still simple objects or objects that contains primitive fields, or these fields can be serializable or parcelable.Now, let suppose I have a really really complex object such as:

```
public class ComplexObject{

private Class1 object1;
private Class2 object2;
....
private ClassN objectN;

}
```

The ith object can contain non-primitive fields. Now if I want to pass the **ComplexObject** to an activity, I have to serialize or parcelize every fields **Class1, Class2, ClassN**. Is there anyway to still pass my **ComplexObject** without doing every serialize or parcelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, your top level object must be either serializeable, or parecelable in order to pass it as an Extra, and for that to work any child objects must also be serializable or parcelable.

These interfaces are the only way that the system knows how to package your data. Without implementing them it would have no way to know how to "break down" an arbitrary object into primitives that can be passed along as an Extra.

Answer (score 2):

If your complexObject is an application model, I suggest putting it in `Application` subclass, where it can be accessed from any component (`Activity`, `Service`). If you have more objects, put them in a `List` or `Map` inside model and pass identifier between `Activities`.

No need to make everything `Parcelable`.

Comment: +1 because you make me think in another way. Let's have a look (another way to share objects among activities) http://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/

Comment: @chipbk10 Exactly. The only problem with the code in that article is it leaks memory: `removeObserver(this)` shall be called in `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it though `Parcelable`

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private Class1 object1;
     private Class2 object2;
     ....
     private ClassN objectN;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeParcelable(object1, flags)
         out.writeParcelable(object2, flags)
         ...
         out.writeParcelable(objectN, flags)
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         object1 = in.readParcelable(Class1.class.getClassLoader());
         object2 = in.readParcelable(Class2.class.getClassLoader());
         ...
         objectN = in.readParcelable(ClassN.class.getClassLoader());
     }
 }
```

I assume that `Class1`, `Class2`, ..., `ClassN` are already implemented `Parcelable`.

Comment: `I assume that Class1, Class2, ..., ClassN are already implemented Parcelable.` Thats the thing though, OP's question is whether he can avoid having to implement parcelable on `Clas1`, `Class2` ..., `classN` To which the answer is no.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Yup, you are right. The answer for the OP's questions is no. Actually I was confused about `An object i can contain non-primitive fields`, so to make it clear I added my answer.